# Vue-router redirect to 404 on every request on server but in local everything works fine

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, cpanel

i am using vue with typescript and i am facing 404 error on server. i am searching so much stuff on google but i can't fix this issue.

Vue Router code

[image]

Live url page

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or other text

Comment: Okay james, actually i am new  in stackoverflow

Comment: @JamesZ do you know to fix this issue?

Comment: Try to host your code on Netlify rather. Should work out of the box. The issue is probably that you don't have a redirect to the index if you hit another path, hence why it:S giving you 404. Netlify handles that for you!

Comment: You may try `createWebHashHistory()` as history mode. If that works, you need to change your server config if you want to use web history mode, see https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: Code and error logs should allways be posted as text, not screenshots.

Answer (score -1):

may one of this answer will help you.

Create a 404.html file with the same content of your index.html file ( in the public folder )

Set the vue router to hash mode ( use createWebHashHistory() not createWebHistory() )

Comment: "Use the same content as your index in your 404 page" is probably bad practice, however, I  think the second part of your answer (as noted in the comments too) is what the op should consider. Consider editing the answer to clarify if you didn't mean what I understood.